# Change ReportPortal database configuration after installation

Tags: reportportal

I have pull docker image of ReportPortal inside AWS ECS. Is it possible to change database sever URL and point to another one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you start the image to run as the container you can set the environment variable to point to your database.

```
RP_DB_HOST=postgres
RP_DB_USER=rpuser
RP_DB_PASS=rppass
RP_DB_NAME=reportportal
```